# Help Poor Tom Now!

Tags: cipher

Tommy tried minimizing

But found he didn’t have the skill

He then turned to graffiTiing

With results too sidespliTTing

His desire to quit was noT

Friends would all aTTesT

Poor Tom's bulb didn’t have the waTTs

**The rhyme is fun but the last words are where the answer is.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The message is:

> HELP TOM

The trick is

> The message is encoded in Morse, where the last words' 'i's are dots and the 'T's are dashes (makes sense if you look at the top of the letters!).

Comment: I was afraid I was making it too simple.  Thanks for helping me develop a higher baseline

Comment: I don't know that it is *too* simple.  Sometime it is nice having a well executed straight forward puzzle.  Just because someone got it quickly doesn't mean everyone will.